# In tensorflow, when should I use CPU, and when should I use GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, cpu

I only use CPU in this scenario:

when I write a emb function, I added **with tf.device('/cpu:0')**

Can anyone tell me when should I use CPU, and when should I use GPU?

```
def emb(inputs, vocabulary_size, embedding_size,
        W_init=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.1, 0.1),
        W_regu=None,
        reuse=None,
        scope=None,
        printable=True):
    with tf.variable_scope(scope, default_name=func_name(), reuse=reuse):
        with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
            emb_mat = slim.model_variable('emb_mat',
                                          shape=[vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                                          initializer=W_init,
                                          regularizer=W_regu)

            outputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(emb_mat, inputs)
            if printable and not tf.get_variable_scope().reuse: print(
                "[info] utils.emb: {0} {1}->{2}".format(outputs.name, inputs.get_shape(), outputs.get_shape()))

            return outputs
```